Omnistudio Flexcard: Dynamically load Picklist options
I'm working on a flexcard where several infos are loaded, and struggling with dynamically generating options.
The requirement is to display a list of N records, where the end user needs to select one from a picklist input on the FlexCard. I need to generate these picklist options dynamically, using the list of records provided by the data source.
I've tried putting in the data source list as an option, but this leads to a fatal error.

Does it need to be a picklist? There are quite a few other options such as a datatable where you can select a row (checkbox) or you can open an Omniscript in a flyout that has an edit block where you can select a row (which looks nice).
Aren't you duplicating the info by displaying the records and then also adding it in a picklist?
